# Converting web socket message to JSON object in Java Play Framework

Tags: java, json, playframework, java-websocket

I am creating a web socket handler using AKKA Actors in Java Play framework. I am trying to parse the message and create JsonNode. I tried

```
public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception
{
    if (message instanceof String)
    {
        JsonNode clientMessage =Json.toJson(message.toString());
        System.out.println(clientMessage);//"{\"messageTxt\":\"hello\",\"id\":\"123\"}"

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try
        {
            JsonNode node = objectMapper.readValue(clientMessage, JsonNode.class);
            JsonNode messageNode = node.get("messageTxt");
            String messagec = messageNode.asText();
            System.out.println("message = " + messagec);

            JsonNode idNode = node.get("id");
            int id = idNode.asInt();
            System.out.println("id = " + id);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /*
            out.tell( response, self());
        */
    }
}
```

I am getting an error

```
[error]  no suitable method found for readValue(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode,java.lang.Class<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode>)

[error]  (argument mismatch; com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode cannot be converted to com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser))
```

How to convert a `JsonNode` Object to `JsonParser` Object? Or is there any better way to create JSON/Map Object.